# How to use the bitbucket api to get list of all pull requests for a repo?

Tags: python, bitbucket

How do I construct a complete REST api request (using python) to retrieve the list of all pull requests for a repo based on some filters?

I'm using the url "https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/YOUR_NAME/REPO_NAME/pullrequests"

I have the client key and secret from the oAuth settings.
[image]

I'm getting the access token using the following POST request.

`$ curl -X POST -u "<key>:<secret>" https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token -d grant_type=client_credentials`

`{"access_token": "{access_token}", "scopes": "pullrequest project team account", "expires_in": 7200, "refresh_token": "{refresh_token}", "token_type": "bearer"}`

I'm getting a forbidden error.
[image]

Is something wrong with the API request?

Comment: Did you try sending a `GET` request to that endpoint? It will return a list of all pull requests (paginated), you can then [add filters](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/meta/filtering) to modify the endpoint.

Comment: Shot in the dark based on common practice. I think the value of the `Authorization` header should be `Bearer <token>`. Not just the token

Comment: @ug_ Thanks a ton! It worked by prefixing "Bearer" before the token value

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make a POST request to get the list of pull requests.

Just do a GET request with all the [filters](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/meta/filtering) you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should have `read` access granted for the user, using whose token you want to retrieve the list of pull requests. Generally 403-forbidden comes when you have no permissions. Once you have at least read access, you can go ahead a get the list using the way suggested by @rajatgoyal715. Also the authorization header value should be `Bearer <token>`. And add one more header `Accept` and set it to `application/json`. Hope this works.